# Can I use duplicate IDs on multiple <template> fragments?

Tags: html, dom, xhtml, w3c-validation

Why does HTML5 validation fail when having duplicate element IDs but on different `<template>`. I'm planning to use only one template at a time so the actual DOM ID won't be duplicated.

something like:

```
<template id="companyAccount">
   <li><label>Company: <input type="text" id="account_name"></label></li>
   <li><label>Street: <input id="account_street" ...
   ...
</template>
<template id="residentialAccount">
   <li><label>Name: <input type="text" id="account_name"></label></li>
   <li><label>Street: <input id="account_street" ...
   ...
</template>
<script>
...
let template = $(isResidential ? '#residentialAccount' : '#companyAccount').get(0).content;
$('#account_info').empty().append(template.cloneNode(true));
</script>
```

Comment: Post example code. How are you "showing only one at a time?"

Comment: @TJBlackman - I've added a sample.

Comment: ID's must be _globally unique_, so that when they exist, there's only ever one of them. It looks like its possible for the same ID to be present more than once on the HTML file, maybe not always, but even if it's just for a second it'll fail. If you must use the same ID, you have to be 100% sure you completely remove one before adding the other. But just use a class instead, or a data-attribute, problem solved.

Comment: As far as I can see, the contents of each template go in to a separate document, so each id is unique within its document, and should not be a validation error. But to be frank, the only person who's going to be able to answer this is sideshowbarker, so you might as well [raise it as an issue on the validator.](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues)

Answer (score 0):

As TJBlackman mentioned each `value` for `id` attributes *must be unique*. However when working with code it's up to *you* to determine if the code being imported contains a duplicate `id`. Additionally I've pretty much stopped using validators for the most part as they aren't well maintained (and the W3C's CSS validator is atrocious) and the consoles, proper error handling and using the XML parser for HTML5 will tell you pretty much everything you need to know.

You have a couple of options. You can use `data-account="residential"` (don't make the mistake of using camelCasing as that will *eventually* put you in direct conflict with the standards bodies) and detect the attribute via `document.querySelectorAll`:

```
function $(o)
{
 var a = true;

 try {document.querySelectorAll(o);}
 catch(err) {a = false; console.log('Error: "'+o+'" is not a valid CSS selector.'); sound.notice();}

 return (a && document.querySelectorAll && document.querySelectorAll(o)) ? document.querySelectorAll(o) : false;
}
```

Usage: `$('[data-account="residential"]')[0].length` and `$('[data-account="residential"]')[0].value`.

Alternatively you can do what I do with my platform which has things tightly integrated though this is the function I use that you might decide to slim down for your specific purposes. You can use `document.createTreeWalker` and literally go through every single element to scan for `walker.currentNode.hasAttribute('id')` to test against `document.getElementById`. This code is used *before* importing XML in to the DOM on my platform:

```
/******** part of larger ajax() function ********/

if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 204)
{}

//This code occurs within the above condition.
var r = jax_id_duplication_prevention(xhr.responseXML,param_id_container_pos,id_container);

if (r)
{
 if (param_id_container_pos=='after') {id_container.parentNode.insertBefore(xml.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],id_container.nextSibling);}
 else if (param_id_container_pos=='before') {id_container.parentNode.insertBefore(document.importNode(xml.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],true),id_container);}
 else if (param_id_container_pos=='first')
 {
  if (id_container.childNodes.length > 0) {id_container.insertBefore(document.importNode(xml.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],true),id_container.firstChild);}
  else {id_container.appendChild(document.importNode(xml.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],true));}
 }
 else if (param_id_container_pos=='inside') {id_container.appendChild(document.importNode(xml.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],true));}
 else if (param_id_container_pos=='replace') {id_container.parentNode.replaceChild(document.importNode(xml.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],true),id_container);}
 else if (param_id_container_pos=='fragment')
 {
  if (option.fragment) {delete option.fragment;}
  option.fragment = document.importNode(new DOMParser().parseFromString(xhr.responseText,'application/xml').childNodes[0],true);
  if (id_container && typeof id_container == 'function') {id_container();}
 }
 else {alert('Error: unknown position to import data to: '+id_container_pos);}
}
/******** part of larger ajax() function ********/

function ajax_id_duplication_prevention(xml,param_id_container_pos,id_container)
{
 var re = true;
 if (typeof id_container == 'string' && id_container.length > 0 && id_(id_container)) {id_container = id_(id_container);}

 if (typeof option.id_fade == 'string' && option.id_fade.length > 0 && id_(option.id_fade)) {element_del(option.id_fade); option.id_fade = '';}

 if (typeof xml.firstChild.hasAttribute == 'function')
 {
  if (xml.firstChild.hasAttribute('id') && xml.firstChild.getAttribute('id').length > 0 && id_(xml.firstChild.getAttribute('id')) && id_(xml.firstChild.id).parentNode.id=='liquid') {change(xml.firstChild.id,'fade');}

  if (xml.firstChild.hasAttribute('id') && xml.firstChild.getAttribute('id').length > 0 && id_(xml.firstChild.id) && !id_(xml.firstChild.id).parentNode.id=='liquid') {re = false;}
  else if (typeof document.createTreeWalker=='function')
  {
   var idz = [];
   try
   {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(xml,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false);

    while (walker.nextNode())
    {
     if (walker.currentNode.hasAttribute('id') && walker.currentNode.getAttribute('id').length > 0)
     {
      if (walker.currentNode.id==undefined && walker.currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='parsererror') {console.log('Error: a parser error was detected.');}
      else if (walker.currentNode.id==undefined) {alert('walker.currentNode.nodeName = '+walker.currentNode.nodeName+'\n\n'+document.serializeToString(xml));}
      else
      {
       for (var i = 0; i<id_('liquid').childNodes.length; i++)
       {
        if (id_('liquid').childNodes[i].nodeType==1 && id_(walker.currentNode.id) && is_node_parent(walker.currentNode.id,id_('liquid').childNodes[i]) && (param_id_container_pos!='replace' || walker.currentNode.id!=id_container.id))
        {
         if (param_id_container_pos != 'replace' && id_container != walker.currentNode.id) {element_del(id_('liquid').childNodes[i]);}//If changing operator test: ajax('get','?ajax=1&web3_url=/'+url_section()+'/'+url_page(),'replace',push_current_id());
        }
       }

       var n = id_(walker.currentNode.id);
       if (in_array(walker.currentNode.id,idz))
       {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('ajax','error_xml');
        fd.append('post_error','Duplicate id <code>'+walker.currentNode.id+'</code>.');
        fd.append('post_url',url_window().split(url_base())[1].split('?')[0]);
        fd.append('post_xml',new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml));
        if (fd) {ajax('post',path+'/themes/',fd);}

        modal.alert('Error: can not import XML, the id \''+walker.currentNode.id+'\' was detected twice in the layer being imported. Duplicated ID\'s break expected functionality and are illegal. While the XML content was not imported it is still possible that the related request was successful. It is possible to override this problem by simply doing a full request (press the Go button in your browser\'s graphic user interface) however if the id is referenced programmatically the website may exhibit unusual behavior.');
        break;
        setTimeout(function()
        {
         history.back();
         push_reload();
         console.log('Developer: duplicate id '+walker.currentNode.id+' was encounterted.');
         if (status >= 9) {modal.xml('Duplicate ID Error', '%3Cp%3EError%3A%20the%20id%20%3Ccode%3E'+walker.currentNode.id+'%3C%2Fcode%3E%20occurred%20twice%20and%20therefore%20the%20page%20can%20not%20be%20viewed.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EFor%20debugging%20and%20fixing%20purposes%20you%20should%20consider%20opening%20the%20URL%20in%20a%20new%20tab.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22center%20margin%22%3E%3Cinput%20onclick%3D%22modal.close()%3B%22%20tabindex%3D%223%22%20type%3D%22button%22%20value%3D%22Close%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E');}
         else {modal.xml('Duplicate ID Error', '%3Cp%3EError%3A%20the%20id%20%3Ccode%3E'+walker.currentNode.id+'%3C%2Fcode%3E%20occurred%20twice%20and%20therefore%20the%20page%20can%20not%20be%20viewed.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22center%20margin%22%3E%3Cinput%20onclick%3D%22modal.close()%3B%22%20tabindex%3D%223%22%20type%3D%22button%22%20value%3D%22Close%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E');}
         re = false;
        },4000);
       }
       else {idz.push(walker.currentNode.id);}
      }

      if (id_(walker.currentNode.id) && (param_id_container_pos!='replace' && walker.currentNode.id!=id_container.id && !is_node_parent(walker.currentNode.id,id_container)))
      {//ajax replace (carousel loader) complications if changed.
       re = false;
       modal.alert('Error: unable to import page, the id \''+walker.currentNode.id+'\' already exists in the DOM.');
       break;
      }
     }
    }
   }
   catch (err) {}//IE9
  }
 }

 return re;
}
```

Regardless of *how* you approach addressing the issue it is *not* one addressed by the standards bodies and *must* be explicitly handled by developers. Failure to handle duplicate `id` attribute/values will result in the wrong element being chosen at some point which may quietly accrue compromised/malformed data over time that no one might notice for *years* and thus could easily hinder if not outright destroy any business relations effected by it. Good luck!